# Codeigniter wrong url to redirect 404

Tags: codeigniter, controller, http-status-code-404

I want to show the 404 page when the wrong url is entered

**TRUE URL**

https://localhost.com/posts/hello_world

**FALSE URL**

https://localhost.com/posts/dsadasd

false url to 404

**Controller**

```
public function read($slug_posts)
{
    $options    = $this->options_model->listing();

    $posts      = $this->posts_model->read($slug_posts);
    #$listing   = $this->posts_model->home();

    $data = array(  'title'         => $posts->post_title.' &#8211; '.$options->option_title,
                    'description'   => $posts->post_description,
                    'posts'         => $posts,
                    #'listing'      => $listing,
                    'content'           =>  'posts/read'
                    );

    $this->load->view('layout/wrapper', $data, FALSE);
}
```

Comment: We can't just sit here and write code for you. It'd be helpful for you and for us if you provide your current stand point and what all you've tried.

Comment: how is your current approach to resolve this problem?. If you edit your question accordingly you might get some feedback, for example, how would your controller `posts` look like?

Comment: `if( $post == 'wrong' ) show_404();`

Comment: @BrianGottier not working :(

Comment: @Vickel add controller

Comment: The point is, there's no way we can know what makes a URL wrong. Your URLs indicate you've got a posts controller, but you're are only showing us a read method. You haven't shown whether you're using custom routes in config/routes.php for this, or if you're remapping inside the controller. You want help, but you've shown us something that is either unrelated code, or not explained what is wrong. How do we know what is wrong with "posts/dsadasd"?? Are you getting any errors that you can tell us about or what? This is Stack Overflow, where a proper question is usually answered very quickly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
public function read($slug_posts)
{
    $options    = $this->options_model->listing();

     $posts      = $this->posts_model->read($slug_posts);
     if ( ! $posts) 
     {
         show_404();
     }
     #$listing   = $this->posts_model->home();

     $data = array(  'title'         => $posts->post_title.' &#8211; '.$options->option_title,
                     'description'   => $posts->post_description,
                     'posts'         => $posts,
                     #'listing'      => $listing,
                     'content'           =>  'posts/read'
                     );

    $this->load->view('layout/wrapper', $data, FALSE);
}
```

If truly understand what your question is, this function show the 404 page when there's no posts based on the slug that you get by the url.